# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "

Tags: java, long-integer, filereader, gatling

I am attempting to access two string values within a simulation.log file and convert the two values to a type long. This is an example of the log file:

[Log Fille](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGlSO.jpg)

When I attempt to access the strings it is telling myself the are empty values. The error I am getting is:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DawT.jpg)

My code is as follows (I understand the statement is not fully closed):

```
File file = new File(simulationLogDir + "/simulation.log");
        FileReader simulationLogReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(simulationLogReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] fields = line.split("\t");
            long responseTime = Long.parseLong(fields[5]) - Long.parseLong(fields[4]);
            if (line.startsWith("REQUEST")) {
                if (fields[7].equals("OK")) {
                    addPassedTest(fields[1], new Request(fields[4],responseTime, fields[7]));
                }
```

Each line in the simulation log is separated by tabbed spaces so the fields array separates each string.

Comment: Please show the log file and the exception in text and not as screenshot

Comment: Check if there are two consecutive tabs in the file.

Comment: @ammoQ thank you! This was not the problem but it allowed me to figure out that it was reading in a line of the file I had no use for. Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

TO SUMMARIZE:

## Double check your file for mistyped spaces.

Based on what I have noticed. Line 8 (Two parseLongs) is really vulnerable to exception, or we can say can throw NumberFormatException especially when it parses non-numerical string.

When does it happen? Based on the title of the question **Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “ ”**, I'm pretty sure you an instance of a line in your file that has a space right after a tab and coincidentally parsed by a Long.parseInt(string num);

To explain it even further, I'll give you 2 Sample Situations.

**SITUATION 1:**
There is a line in your file that look like this

> REQUEST (tab) test_12345_54321 (tab) 1 (tab) Macbook Request (tab) (space) 1490183061440 (tab) 1490183061321 (tab) OK

This line will then be splitted in such manner as follows:

> fields[0] = REQUEST
> fields[1] = test_12345_54321
> fields[2] = 1
> fields[3] = Macbook Request
> **fields[4] = (space) 1490183061440** 
> **fields[5] = 1490183061321**
> fields[6] = OK

Parsing 4th index and fifth index will be:

> Long.parseLong(fields[4]) -> **space can't be parsed as results to NumberFormatException**
>
> Long.parseLong(fields[5]) = 1490183061321 -> works fine

---

**SITUATION 2:**
There is a line in your file that look like this

> REQUEST (tab) test_12345_54321 (tab) 1 (tab) Macbook Request (tab) 1490183061440 (tab) (space) (tab) 1490183061321 (tab) OK

This line will then be splitted in such manner as follows:

> fields[0] = REQUEST
> fields[1] = test_12345_54321
> fields[2] = 1
> fields[3] = Macbook Request
> **fields[4] = 1490183061440** 
> **fields[5] = (space)**
>
> fields[5] = 1490183061321
> fields[6] = OK

Parsing 4th index and fifth index will be:

> Long.parseLong(fields[4]) = 1490183061440 -> works fine
>
> Long.parseLong(fields[5]) -> **space can't be parsed as results to NumberFormatException**